# code: 'AccessDenied', region: null, Error when I'm trying to create Bucket in S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

this is my object of info:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

 let S3 = new AWS.S3({
   region: process.env.region,
   accessKeyId: process.env.accessKeyId,
   secretAccessKey: process.env.secretAccessKey
 });
```

This is my function of the class for creating a bucket

```
  create_bucket(){
    S3.createBucket(
      {
        Bucket: 'bucket-create-test'
      },
      (error, success) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error)
        }

        if (success) {
          console.log(success) 
        }
        else {
          console.log('Not working properly')
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

all the information all exactly copied from AWS panel and they are not wrong, but I get the error:

```
code: 'AccessDenied',
region: null,
```

I expected this function to make a bucket successfully but unfortunately didn't.

Comment: What is `process.env` populated with? Did you actually set your credentials as environment variables or have you just done `aws configure` for example? If so, just remove the `accessKeyId` and `secretAccessKey` and let the SDK find credentials automatically using the credentials provider chain.

Comment: FYI you no longer have to use callbacks with the AWS JavaScript SDKs. You can use `await S3.createBucket(params).promise()`, for example.